# when to store data different collections MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling

I want to store events occurred during a week in MongoDB. Each week can have 300-400 events.
One week's events are independent of another week and at a time i fetch or process only one week at time.( Never joining two or more week)

All event objects have same properties but different values.

Is it good to create separate collection for a each week or in same collection?

Comment: How long do you need to save this information (about events)?

Comment: At most one year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By given information, I would choose to store everything in one collection, because 300-400 events per week is really a small amount of entities (documents).

The document schema depends on the project needs/details, but as minimum I would add separated the `year` and `week` elements for the filtering purpose

Document example:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5c530d202029a5144454f9c2"),
    "year": 2019,
    "week": 10,
    "event": {
        "date": ISODate("2019-03-07T11:00:01.022Z")
        "name": "some event name",
        "message": "some message"
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean separate document for each week or one document for one event identified by unique week_id.

Comment: One document per event (1 year x 12 months x 400 events = 4800 documents, this amount of documents is  nothing for MongoDB).